# MySQLi prepared statement error

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've got the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM PAS WHERE KLANT_NR = (SELECT KLANT_NR FROM klanten WHERE VOORNAAM = ? AND ACHTERNAAM = ?)";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $klantVoornaam, $klantAchternaam);
```

This however generates the following error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND ACHTERNAAM = ?)' at line 1
```

The two variables are $_POST strings..

Strange thing is, if i add two strings in the normal query instead of the '?'s, the query works fine. I can't figure out why the prepared statement doesn't work then...

Comment: Are both  `VOORNAAM` and `ACHTERNAAM` string type?

Comment: You can see last executed query in your mysql general query log. Show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the awnser myself, it was related to an other $query i placed below..

stupid mistake, thanks for the help though.

Comment: Then delete this question since there's no additional value in it for the community.